# '.Model' not working with '.Where' in GORM Model

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, backend, go-gorm

`model := dbconn.Model(&database.Template{}).Where(`?=ANY(tags)`, tagstring).Find(&templates)`

This GORM query does not work
I'm using POSTGRES btw.
The struct im working with here is:

```
type Template struct {
    ID     uint           `json:"template_id"`
    Name   string         `json:"template_name"`
    FlowUI string         `json:"flowUI"`
    Tags   pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:varchar(255)[]" json:"tags"`
}
```

But if I instead do

`model := dbconn.Where(`?=ANY(tags)`, tagstring).Find(&templates)`
and print out the templates it gives the correct answer

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with "does not work"? And what are you trying to achieve with the first query that can't be done with the second one?

Comment: I'm using pagination on the model, `paginated := pg.Response(model, r, &[]database.Template{})
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&paginated)`

Comment: I don't see how the model is related the pagination, and I also don't know what `pg.Response` is. That said, for a simple pagination you have to limit the result and keep track of the offset, like in [this](https://dev.to/rafaelgfirmino/pagination-using-gorm-scopes-3k5f) example. The issue is completely unrelated to the `gorm.Model` (which is just a helper struct you don't even need). Maybe it's better if you try to go through the example in the link and - in case any question arises - you create a new thread for that specific problem?

Comment: I use this library to paginate for me works well with GORM you just have to pass a model to it. "github.com/morkid/paginate"

Comment: I see. Well, accoring to the manual of the pagination library you have to put the `.Where` in front of the `.Model()`, e.g. `model := dbconn.Where(?=ANY(tags), tagstring).Model(&database.Template{})`. I figure `Find()` is not supported then, but that's for a reason. Either you query the data on your own, implementing your own pagination logic (as in my link above), or you leave all the querying to you pagination lib with `pg := paginate.New(); page := pg.With(model).Request(req).Response(&[]Article{})`. You can't have both and I'm not really sure that the libary's approach is a good one anyway

Comment: Continuation: The library comes with some ugly tight coupling to http requests and how to paginate (e.g. no cursor-based pagination).

Comment: Hmmm makes sense, thanks for the help, new to golang and GORM will try to refactor my pagination methods, Library worked fine till now and made it super easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I am understanding your question correctly. Based on the two queries you provided, it looks like you are wondering why you do not need to specify `.Model(&database.Template{})`.

You didn't provide the code that shows what `templates` is set to, I'm assuming that it is initialized as follows:

```
var templates database.Template
```

With this assumption, it is not necessary to provide the `.Model(...)`. This is because the destination `&templates` already has the struct information that Gorm needs.

That said there are a handful of exceptions where you do need to provide the Model or Table. These are when neither the query or the destination provide the type being used so Gorm doesn't know what table to use. For example, if you write SQL directly and have a custom result object type.

Here is the Gorm documentation on Query: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html I have found their documentation to be quite helpful and thorough.

Comment: Hey, I want to use the model for pagination later that's why I want the WHERE code to work with the MODEL Keyword.

Comment: paginated := pg.Response(model, r, &[]database.Template{})
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&paginated)